# i am trying to pull text from a table on a jsp using page object selenium

Tags: java, jsp, selenium

so i am using selenium page objects and i've found the correct row and given it an Id but it keeps giving me a null pointer in the console but i have no clue what is returning null.

here is the page,

```
    @FindBy(id = "status")
private WebElement confirmedEmergencySignIn;

@FindBy(className = "navbar-brand")
private WebElement dashboardLink;

public EmergenciesInListPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver, PageTitle.EMERGENCYINLIST, PagePath.EMERGENCYOUTLIST);

    // COMPULSORY
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public Boolean checkEmergencySinedIn(String textToCheck) {
    return confirmedEmergencySignIn.getText().equals(textToCheck);
}
```

here is the selenium test,

```
    @Test
public void testToShowAllUsersThatAreSignedinOnTheEmergencyList() {
    quickSignIn();
    emergencyPage = dashboardPage.clickEmergencyListLink();
    emergencyPage.clickInOutDropdown();
    emergencyPage.clickSetStatusInLink();
    assertTrue(emergenciesInListPage.checkEmergencySinedIn(STATUS_IN));
    assertTrue(isOnThisPage(PagePath.EMERGENCYINLIST));
}
```

and here is the section of the Jsp that contains the table.
the table populates itself when data is present,

`<div class = "containter">
        <div class = "table">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                        <th> First Name </th>
                        <th> Last Name </th>
                        <th> Status </th>
                        <c:forEach items="${allPeople}" var="P">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${P.user.forenames}</td>
                            <td>${P.user.surname}</td>
                            <td id="status">${P.status}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
     </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is there is more than 1 id of `'status'` since you are looping over `${allPeople}`, and the property

`@FindBy(id = "status")
private WebElement confirmedEmergencySignIn;`

is not a collection. You would need to make this a collection or make the Id Unique.

Comment: how could i go about doing this?

Comment: To make the Id unique you could cobine the forename and surname but there could always be the case that you will have someone with the same forname and surname so maybe a userId?

Comment: i see what you mean but all i really want to pull from the table is the status as the test is just to see if anyone is signed in.

Comment: You would need to make the property a collection rather than a single instance e.g. a `List<WebElement>`

Comment: Just tried that, but i'm still getting null parameters

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what is actually null and not being populated?